# Camel-NMR not available in servicemix 5.x

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I have been trying my head around the camel NMR component and wanted to practice some of use cases on servicemix platform. But to my surprise, I could not find the nmr feature in servicemix 5.3 version which I have.

Is support for NMR in servicemix withdrawn? Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes JBI support in ServiceMix 5.x is dropped. JBI is dead, do not use that.
The NMR component was part of JBI and hence dropped.

Just use pure Camel in ServiceMix.

- http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/4.4.x/jbi/components/servicemix-camel.html
- http://gnodet.blogspot.se/2010/12/thoughts-about-servicemix.html

Comment: But how would i achieve inter-bundle communication by using pure camel.. i tried the direct & seda component but they work within camelcontext and hence won't be of use in my case. The workaround I am using is, osgi services for communicating across bundles. But I want to know if that is the only way and is that the best approach?

Comment: Use the vm component, for example.

Comment: okay, I had tried using vm component in past but hit dead end when a request object passed from one bundle to another will not get type cast as each bundle has its own classloader. Will try again afresh. Thank you very much for the information and suggestion to Claus and Achim.

Answer (score 0):

NMR is not available but we can use direct-vm component which is working same as NMR.